# Is there a way to override top level dependencies in FastAPI?

Tags: pytest, fastapi

In this FastAPI app we use Auth0 to authenticate, so it is a top level dependency. Is it possible to override it in a test? I setup FastAPI following this guide: https://auth0.com/blog/build-and-secure-fastapi-server-with-auth0/

```py
app = FastAPI(
    ...
    dependencies=[Security(auth.verify)],
)
```

I tried adding the override as usual with dependencies, but this doesn't seem to have any effect:

```py
def get_test_user(*args, **kwargs):
    return {"sub": "testuser"}

# Try 1
app.dependency_overrides[VerifyToken.verify] = get_test_user
# Try 2
auth = VerifyToken()
app.dependency_overrides[auth.verify] = get_test_user
# Try 3
auth = VerifyToken()
app.dependency_overrides[Security(auth.verify)] = Security(get_test_user)
```

Comment: The snippets you've included works as expected with option 2, so I'm guessing you might not have shared the actual code you're using - it'd be helpful with an actual self-contained example. See https://gist.github.com/matslindh/3319f1689b0590e5b66a5f98f1e7749c for an example that outputs `test` when running with `pytest -s`. If this solves your issue I'll post it as an answer, but since you say you've tried that exact thing, I'm not sure if this is a solution.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, sorry for the late response. You are right, I didn't include everything to not overcomplicate things, but it seems that it is impossible to convey otherwise. Updated question with the actual details.

Comment: If you're doing `auth = VerifyToken()` - you're creating a new object each time, and the function reference will be different, since they're different objects. In that case you'll have to import the actual `auth` instance from _your app_, then use that as the key in `dependency_overrides`, so that you actually get the _same function_ as the key.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the quick response and your help. Tried it by importing not only the app but also the auth and overriding this and it works now. You may add this as the answer, will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Great that you finally got it solved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are overriding a dependency it's important that they key in `dependency_overrides` *is the exact same function* as what is being used as a dependency. This means that if you're creating an object instance and then using a function from that instance as a dependency in your code, the override has to use the *exact same function from the same instance* as the override key:

```
from .main import app, auth

..

app.dependency_overrides[auth.verify] = Security(get_test_user)
```

If you create a new instance in your test file before defining the override, you're creating a new set of function references - they do no longer refer to the original function that is bound to your original object.

This is also the case when returning a closure / function from another function, commonly used with role functions as dependencies, such as `Depends(has_role("foo"))` where `has_role` returns a function bound with `foo` as the role name. In those cases you can wrap the function in a `lru_cache` from `functools`, so that the same instance gets returned for the same parameter each time.